# Сериализовать поля класса в json в зависимости от условия

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Мне нужно сериализовать класс Incident в json.

```
class Incident
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public string fincertId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public string fixationAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
    public lawEnforcementRequest lawEnforcementRequest { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 5)]
    public string assistance { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 6)]
    public string vectorCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 7)]
    public List<serviceType> serviceType = new List<serviceType>();

    [JsonProperty(Order = 8)]
    public string typeOfAttack { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 9)]
    public List<measuresAndRecomendations> measuresAndRecomendations = new List<measuresAndRecomendations>();

    [JsonProperty(Order = 10)]
    public location location { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 11)]
    public classification classification { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 12)]
    public List<antifraud> antifraud = new List<antifraud>();

    [JsonProperty(Order = 13)]
    public List<malware> malware = new List<malware>();

    [JsonProperty(Order = 13)]
    public List<traffic> traffic = new List<traffic>();

    [JsonProperty(Order = 14)]
    public finalReport finalReport { get; set; }
}
```

В этом классе листы malware и traffic ситуативные, я  выбираю один из них.

Можно ли написать какое-то условие, чтобы выбирался только один лист или лучше создать два разных класса ?

Comment: Да, только один из них.

Comment: Делается по документу и крайне нежелательно, чтобы был узел даже с null. Это два схожих документа , в которых различия только в этом месте(либо malware либо traffic).

Comment: Вы только сериализовать будете, верно?

Comment: Сейчас это главная цель,да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете избежать сериализации если укажете NullValueHandling.Ignore

```
void Main()
{
    var source = new Incident {
        Id = 1,
        malware = null,
    };

    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    });
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Incident
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<malware> malware = new List<malware>();
}

public class malware
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Выведет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вам нужно только для каких-то конкретных свойств указать:

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
// или
[JsonProperty("property_name", NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
```

Аналогично [есть ещё](https://www.newtonsoft.com/Json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm) и DefaultValueHandling

Вообще же, можно писать практически любые [условия](https://www.newtonsoft.com/JSON/help/html/SerializeConditionalProperty.htm) если добавлять к определению класса поля с названием ShouldSerializeНазваниеПоля.

```
public bool ShouldSerializemalware()
{
    return this.malware.Count() > 0;
}
```

Ссылки по теме:

- [How to ignore a property in class if null, using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6507889/5752652)
- [Can Newtonsoft Json.NET skip serializing empty lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11320968/5752652)